# TypeError when running Jest tests with the emitWarning function

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I'm encountering the following type error when running my tests in Jest.

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "warning" argument must be of type string or an instance of Error. Received an instance of Error
```

The error only occurs when running Jest tests.
It does not occur in normal execution.
The following is a simplified code to illustrate the error.

```js
function emitWarningWithError() {
    const error = new Error('foo')
    error.name = 'name'
    error.message = 'foo'
    process.emitWarning(error)
}

function emitWarningWithString() {
    process.emitWarning('bar')
}

describe('emitWarning', () => {
    it('should not cause an error using Error', () => {
        emitWarningWithError();
    });

    it('should not cause an error using a string', () => {
        emitWarningWithString();
    });
});
```

What do I need to do?

Comment: How do you bootstrap your test? I stumbled over this error when I had a `beforeEach` function which initialized the listeners before each test and thus exceeding the maximum number of allowed listeners of my `EventEmitter`. Changed it to a `beforeAll` and it worked fine!

Comment: thanks @Ele your comment solved the problem for me too!

Comment: Unfortunately, the error that you have is not the same here

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled over this error when I had a `beforeEach`-function which initialized the listeners before each test and thus exceeding the maximum number of allowed listeners of my EventEmitter. Changed it to a `beforeAll`-function and it worked fine.